# HTML filepicker multi - get files in use

Tags: html, firefox, multifile-uploader, filepicker

The following problem occured using Firefox v73 on Window 7:

In my code i use a multi-file-picker in html to upload up to 100-files parallal:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```

The files will be sent to a REST-API which process them afterwards.
When i select a single file (in the file-explorer) which is currently in use, i get a error-message (probably by window) which tells me, that the file cannot be picked because it is in use.
If i try to pick multiple-files which contain one or more files in use, i have no error occuring but the upload seems to stop when the file-in-use is reached and waiting for the file to be released.
This leads to request to wait for a timeout (which is 1 minute in my case).

Is there any option to catch the problem (in use file) before trying to upload the files?

PS: I've tried the same in Chrome and it returns a error before sending the request to the REST-API.

Comment: Can you show your ajax call?

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like an OS issue.
Something is locking your file from being accessed and this needs a fix on your side.

I doubt it will be a common issue, and it's quite hard to build a solution without being able to experience the same issue but one thing you can try is to *read* your Files before you send them. This can be done quite conveniently with [`Blob.prototype.arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method, which can be polyfilled.

To avoid a lot I/O, you can even try to read only a small part of it, thanks to [`Blob.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice)  method.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('inp');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = async(evt) => {
  testAllFilesAvailability(input.files)
    .then(() => console.log('all good'))
    .catch(() => console.log('some are unavailable'));
}

function testAllFilesAvailability(files) {
  return Promise.all(
    [...files].map(file =>
      file.slice(0, Math.min(file.size, 4)) // don't load the whole file
      .arrayBuffer() // Blob.prototype.arrayBuffer may require a polyfill
    )
  );
}
```

```html
<pre>
1. Select some files from the input
2. Change one of this files name on your hard-drive or even delete it
3. Press the button
</pre>

<input type="file" multiple id="inp">
<button id="btn">Test Availability</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Kaiido for the solution. There are your +50 reputation. Lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple files why you don't use 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Using jQuery is currently not a option for me due to technical limitations at customer side.